# setOnClickListner

Tags: eclipse-indigo

I am totally new to Android development , recently i bought Lynda.com Android App Development video learning course.

I am facing following problem:

1. Created new project
2. Created new xml file with text field only
3. Then go to Main.xml(that was created by defualt) and replace the default text field with button.
4. Then go to Main.Java and try calling added button by code "Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);"
5. After that I tried to call the setOnClickListner function by " b. " but there is no option with 
   name of setOnClickListner.

I follow the exact steps as told by tutor in videos .. I am using Android SDK 12 ,Eclipse Indigo and working on Gingerbread 2.3.3. Any solution in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Possible situations:

- Make sure you imported android.widget.Button
- > `"Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);"`

Usually it is called:

```
"Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);"
```

if you have defined the button correctly in the main.xml file. Also make sure you are not importing android.R

- I suppose it is a typo but it is actually written setOnClickListener()

Cheers

Comment: thx man, strange though by adding the android.R i actually able to get the "Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);" but still cant fix the setOnClickListener(){typo before} issue even after adding import android.widget.Button ..